# Python: How can I choose which module to import when they are named the same

Tags: python, import, namespaces

Lets say I'm in a file called `openid.py` and I do :

```
from openid.consumer.discover import discover, DiscoveryFailure
```

I have the `openid` module on my pythonpath but the interpreter seems to be trying to use my `openid.py` file. How can I get the library version?

(Of course, something other than the obvious 'rename your file' answer would be nice).

Comment: 'rename your file'

Comment: What's the reason for not renaming the file? It seems like small fix compared to be looking for a way around it.

Comment: The file should semantically be called openid, since it is in a module with "types" of aliases. openid is the name of the type.

Comment: are these modules located in parent module `aliases`?

Comment: yes, they all are. but inside the "openid.py" file i can't seem to get access to the "openid" library. That's the main problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thats the reason absolute imports have been chosen as the new default behaviour. However, they are not yet the default in 2.6 (maybe in 2.7...). You can get their behaviour now by importing them from the future:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

You can find out more about this in the PEP metnioned by Nick or (easier to understand, I think) in the document ["What's New in Python 2.5"](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html).

Answer (score 3):

**Rename it**. This is the idea behind name spaces. your `openid` could be a sub-module in your top module `project`. your `email` will clash with top module `email` in stdlib.

because your openid is not universal, it provides a special case for your project.

Comment: Actually, I think the idea behind name spaces is *not* to have to rename it to something unique ;) myproject.openid is something different than openid.

With the new absolute imports, import openid will always get the system-wide (e.g. stdlib) module and the relative .openid will get the openid submodule in the current module.

Comment: of course it isn't. **If** he his module `project` than he should be using `project.openid`. It's not clear why OP is doing what he's doing, but if he doesn't have module `project`, then he should rename `openid` to something else.

Comment: correct. outside the package it is pkg.openid. But inside the "openid.py" file i can't get access to the "openid" library. That's the main problem.

Answer (score 2):

I won't get into the polemics on renaming and instead focus on showing you how to do what you want (whether it's "good for you" or not;-). The solution is not difficult...

Just set `__path__`! A little demonstration:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/modules /tmp/packages
$ mkdir /tmp/packages/openid
$ echo 'print "Package!"' > /tmp/packages/openid/__init__.py
$ gvim /tmp/modules/openid.py
$ PYTHONPATH='/tmp/modules:/tmp/packages' python -c'import openid'
Module!
Package!
```

this shows a *module* openid managing to import a homonymous *package* even though the module's path comes earlier in sys.path, **and** `sys.modules['openid']` is clearly already set at that time. And all the "secret" is in openid.py's simple code...:

```
print "Module!"
__path__ = ['/tmp/packages']
import openid
```

without the `__path__` assignment, of course, it would only emit `Module!`.

Also works for importing submodules within the package, of course. Do:

```
$ echo 'print "Submod!"' > /tmp/packages/openid/submod.py
```

and change openid.py's last line to

```
from openid import submod
```

and you'll see:

```
$ PYTHONPATH='/tmp/modules:/tmp/packages' python -c'import openid'
Module!
Package!
Submod!
$
```

Comment: Regarding sys.modules['openid'] being set. You also said this in another comment, but I'm not so sure. Why would that be the case? Is the current file automatically added to sys.modules? A quick test.py < "import sys; print 'test' in sys.modules.keys()", when run, suggests otherwise!?

Comment: As I replied to the other comment: the one file that's run as the main module goes into `sys.modules['__main__']` instead (as its `__name__` is artificially and conventionally set to `__main__`). That's why I'm **import**ing openid here, to show that `__path__` still works. If all you need w/openid.py is to run it as main then there's no reason to have it in sys.path.

Comment: I thought that the OP's problem stems simply from the fact that '.' comes earlier in sys.path, so the current directory is searched for 'openid' where the importing openid.py script is found. But if you shift the 'interesting' directories of sys.path to its front, the other 'openid' (the module) is found first, and everything is fine.

Comment: It's extremely confusing (you and the OP both appear to do that sometimes) to refer to the _package_ openid as "the module" -- openid.py is the module, directory openid with a file `__init__.py` is the package. If openid.py is never imported, then hacking sys.path works; however, my answer works more generally (whether openid.py is imported or run as main script), _and_ avoids messing with system-global settings.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I will also try to improve on my wording :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative or absolute imports (depending on the specifics of your situation), which are covered in [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) most recently.  Of course, seriously, you should not be creating naming conflicts like this and should rename your file.

Comment: Even if the semantically correct name for the file is openid? Like if it is in a directory of types of aliases along with, email, webpage, domain, etc?

Comment: @Paul: Even then.  If it's in a "directory of types of aliases", then that really ought to be a package, and then it's pkg.openid, which is unambiguous.

Comment: correct. outside the package it is pkg.openid. But inside the "openid.py" file i can't get access to the "openid" library. That's the main problem.

Comment: @Paul: sure you can.  Use an absolute import (from __future__ import absolute_import) and do 'import openid', which will resolve as basically (pseudo-path-structure) /openid, instead of /pkg/openid.

Answer (score -1):

You could try shuffling `sys.path`, to move the interesting directories to the front before doing the import.

Comment: Won't help if `sys.modules['openid']` is already set, as it would be in the OP's case as he's in `openid.py`.

Comment: @Alex Why would that be the case? Is the current file automatically added to sys.modules? A quick test.py < "import sys; print sys.modules.keys()", when run, suggests otherwise!?

Comment: A module that's _imported_ gets added to sys.modules under its real name; the one file that's run as the "main program" gets the conventional name of `__main__` instead. But if you're running that openid.py as the main module then there's no reason to have it on sys.path in the first place!